# NS change but MX points to domain

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, ns-record

I will be changing the nameservers for a client to my server for a new website. I will be using Cloudflare as it also adds SSL.

The problem is that he has an MX record pointing to `mail.example.com`. If I change the `NS` records for that domain, and point the `A` record of `example.com` to my server, the `MX` record will also point to my server rather than the old server, correct?

How can I get Cloudflare to point the mail back to his old server?

Here are the DNS settings I will be using on Cloudflare:

```
example.com. A 192.168.0.89
www CNAME my.server.example
example.com. MX mail.example.com (priority 10)
```

Comment: "point the A record of example.com to my server, the MX record will also point to my server rather than the old server, correct?" No. Each record is independant of others. If you change the `A` one, it does not change anything for the `MX` record (except indirectly of course if the `MX` record references a name for which you are changing the `A` record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a host for your MTA, like `A mail.example.com 192.0.2.123` and let the `MX` point to `mail.example.com`. The name of the server is most likely relevant (`mail.*`), because it may have its own certificates for TLS.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am afraid I cannot upvote your answer, but thank you!